# How can i skip 0041 and 0 before storing phone number in controller variable using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I need to remove 0041 and 0 before Number because some users entered 0041 or 0 before 12345678. So, i just add 0041 static

```
$order->phone       =        "0041" . $request->phone;
```

So, if user entered 0041 or 0 before number it should be skipped and number will stored 004112345678.

Please give me any idea for it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could come in help https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr` to check for the first digits. Use it in a conditional as such:

```
if(substr($phone, 0, 4) !==  "0041"){
    $phone = "0041" . $phone;
}
```

Comment: The same solution can be applied for the second scenario (a user entering 0 before the number). As far as I know, the actual number part of a phone number never begins with a zero anyway - so stripping any leading zeroes makes sense.

Comment: I think it's not working if `0` preceded. [Checked here](https://eval.in/1056900)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) with fixed length `12`

```
<?php
//$month = "004112345678";
$month = "012345678";
echo str_pad($month, 12, "0041xxxxxxxx", STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1056899)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match("/^(0041|0)(?P<test>\d+)/", $number, $matches)){
  $phone = "0041" . $matches['test'];
}
```